# highlight current menu item with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to higlight current category. I can do it like that, no problem:

**javascript**

```
var url = document.URL;
$('.nav a[href="'+url+'"]').addClass('active');
```

**html**

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://wholewebaddress.com/cat.php?id=1">Category 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://wholewebaddress.com/cat.php?id=2">Category 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

but i dont want to link to `http://wholewebadress.com/catphp?cat.php?id=1` in html codes, instead i want to link to `cat.php?id=1`. So i want my html codes look like below;

```
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="cat.php?id=1">Category 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="cat.php?id=2">Category 2</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Looks like, i need to edit my javascript code. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The following adds the active class to any link that contains `id=1` in the URL:

```
$('.nav a[href*="id=1"]').addClass('active');
```

You can change the matching part (*"id=1"*) to select whatever URL criteria you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use `var url = location.pathname + location.search;`

[W3Schools information](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_pathname.asp)

Edit: since it seems to need to parse for the ending:

```
var ending = url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Comment: `.pathname` is without the querystring

Comment: Can you `console.log(url)` with this and tell us what you get?

Comment: my console says: `"/folder/cat.php?id=1"`

Comment: And `document.url` doesn't include the folder?

Comment: it doesnt work because i dont link like `<a href="folder/cat.php?id=1">cat1</a>` if i do like that, problem will get solved i guess. but i need to link like `<a href="cat.php?id=1">cat1</a>` so need to edit javascript.

Comment: thanks but i'm afraid console outcome didn't change at all.

Comment: What does `console.log(ending)` return?